# Change the title of a partially good and answered closed question

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256353/is-there-an-adwords-api-implementation-in-go/12258671#12258671) was closed as non constructive.

I won't argue against that as

- there were two questions in one
- only the Pythia can answer the one appearing in the title

But I feel this question and its answer might be useful if renamed accordingly to the good question

> "How to do a SOAP call in Go today ?"

I don't do it myself because I'm the answerer and I'm not sure this would be seen as correct.

Could you please tell me if I may proceed or if it's better not to make such a substantial change ?

Comment: Link to the question please?

Comment: @Bart Ooops... Fixed.

Comment: in the title you suggest, I'd consider changing fuzzy "today" with something more substantial, with something like "while there are no Google APIs for Go yet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably edit about 50% of the questions I answer. I don't see a problem with this.

You have to be careful not to change the question and to not change any code but if you can make a question *better* and less likely to be closed or more likely to be re-opened then you should do so.

In your particular case I would change it as you've described to re-focus the question into a "good" one. However, you should also ensure that you don't invalidate your own, or others, answers, which would imply that you have to retain the actual question.

I wouldn't vote to re-open this question; even if you reword it.